# Is there a role for overall management for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-management, identity-management

I need to manage the GCP for my client (who is not really technical person). For now he is granting me email and password of the account (not good I know).

I checked the documentation of GCP and from what I see, IAM is Per-Project-based. However I need to create projects, manage all his projects too.

Is there a general role that I can manage near-everything (billing is not my concern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCP an Organization [1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) is the root resource which contains the projects. You can get a more detailed explanation and a descriptive diagram about GCPs hierarchy on this page: [2](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy). To create and manage projects [3](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) within an organization you will need to have the roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin role as you will find explained here: [4](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#permissions_and_roles).

You can further read this article on the Google Cloud Platform Blog which explains how to organize your GCP organization [5](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/05/mapping-your-organization-with-the-Google-Cloud-Platform--resource-hierarchy.html).

---